# Using the iOS Focus feature, is it possible to allow calls and texts from a different set of people?

Tags: ios, notifications, focus

Using the iOS Focus feature (on an iPhone running iOS 17.2 in case it matters) is it possible to have the following?

While the work Focus mode is on...

- A phone call should only come through if it's from person A or B
- A text message should only come through if it's from person A, B, C, or D

So, to be clear, phone calls from persons C or D should still be silenced exactly in the same way as those from everyone outside of the allowed people list. Only text messages from them should be allowed to break through the focus.

I was asked about this setup and couldn't figure it out. In this particular example the set of allowed people for calls and text messages overlap, but I'm curious if they can be different *at all*.